# Swipable cell issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I want to make cell swipe funcationality like my image, I am using https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit but due to my cell design I am unable to achieve this type of functionality.

There is extra space in trailing and bottom so my swipe action is not as perfect as my design.

What I want to achieve.

[image: Swipe Cell]

What I achieve till now

[image: achieved Result]

How can I achieve this type of functionality, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me your cell design in storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

In your cell design, the white box has a space between the top, bottom, left and right. First, make it fully covered in the entire cell to the top and bottom. And add the **Cell Spacing** between the cells.

To archive this, you can add the header and footer to the `tableView`.

```
let cellSpaceHeight = 5

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return MenuArray!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(cellSpaceHeight)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(cellSpaceHeight)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let FooterView = UIView()
    FooterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return FooterView
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue . //Set the color same as cell content background color
    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Reminder") { action, indexPath in
        // handle action by updating model with deletion
    }
    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "events")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

    return [deleteAction]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
    var options = SwipeOptions()
    options.expansionStyle = .destructive
    options.transitionStyle = .border
    return options
}
```

And my `tableviewCell.xib` is:

[image]

Set the `cell` `contentView` background color to blue. And `tableView` background color to `Default`

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to cover whole cell from leading, traling

Comment: Don't cover leading and trailing. Cover top and bottom

Comment: And add clear color to cell content background and blue color to tableview background color.

Comment: can you make me a simple demo for this? I want to achieve same as per my screenshot

Comment: I have done it in my code. But You cannot remove the trailing space. It will be there only. That is the default behavior. When we swipe left the cell, the entire cell becomes moves to the left.

Comment: What about leading and trailing space? I also don't want that. Also if possible can I get that user has swiped cell so that we can make it possible through constraints of we can change background color of cell when user swipe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198363/discussion-between-jitendra-modi-and-vinu-jacob).

Comment: just add trailing constraint and set it zero on the swipe method @JitendraModi, this answer is already perfect